# How to access and traverse a Java collection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

A JSP file has the following code, which accesses a collection of *User* objects held in a *session* variable:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${not empty users}">
   <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
      <option value="${user.userId}" selected>
          <c:out value="${user.firstname} - ${campaign.lastname}"></c:out>
      </option>
      ...
```

The above works and displays a list of all users.

What is the correct way to access the collection of users from a javascript function (defined in the same file) so that it can then be iterated over in a similar way?

I have tried:

```
var users = '<%= (java.util.Collection<org.mycompany.User>) session.getAttribute("users") %>';
```

However, this just returns a string with a list of the object names:

```
[org.mycompany.User@10330a7b, org.mycompany.User@6f5198c, org.mycompany.User@456039e5, 
org.mycompany.User@30790cf8, org.mycompany.User@5b4286a4, org.mycompany.User@6c95a7ca
```

Thanks

Comment: Those `User` objects are server-side objects that exist in the context of the servlet environment. They're not transmitted to the client (the web browsers accessing your site) unless you write code to serialize and transmit them yourself.

Comment: This isn't working because toStirng on an array is a not the way to go. anyway you will need to serialize /deserialize, perhaps using jackson

Comment: var array1 = users.split( ... ) , does that help

Answer (score -1):

You can convert that string into an array of user names like this

```
var userArray = users.match(/User@([0-9a-f]+)/gi);
```

Hope that answers the problem..